# Upgrading Magento

Tags: magento, installation, upgrade

Just a quick question involving upgrading Magento.  I currently have version 1.4.1 and would like to update to the newest version.  I tried upgrading through the Magento Connect and can not get that to work.  And my host will not give me SSH access so I can't do it that way.

It's very frusterating, what are my other options? Can I just download the new set of files and replace those, but keep the old database?  Will that work?

Not sure the best way to approach this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search SO to get similar answers:

- disable all 3rd party extensions
- disable custom themes
- upgrade (you can do version by version also)
- turn on your theme
- turn on extensions one by one and debug